# Some random person name and details generator?

Tags: data-request

I am looking for some website/tool that can allow me to generate names, some random id for certain number of people at once. I came across some websites but they only do one at a time and there was no easy way to download those. I am looking to generate for about 10K names and ids (other details will be more than welcome). Is anyone familiar with any such tool that can allow me to generate names and unique ids?

Answer (score 6):

There are also libraries for [Python](https://github.com/joke2k/faker), [php](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker), and [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~jasonk/Data-Faker-0.07/).

For the Python Faker library, you would do something along the lines of

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

for _ in range(0,10000):
    print( '{} - {}'.format( fake.uuid4(), fake.name() ) )
```

You can localize the name generator and you can also seed it for reproducible generations.

Comment: Please note that faker is being replaced by fake-factory https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-factory , and that there is no uuid4

Comment: @philshem: The pypi link already resolves to the new package, see https://github.com/joke2k/faker/issues/331

Comment: @philshem: Also: I see no indication that the uuid4 method should be removed. Either way, it is a oneliner (https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/faker/providers/misc/__init__.py#L83) and faker allows for your own Provider to wrap the functionality

Comment: I think this will generate ids like 1,2,3 and so on.I wanted to generate ids like they normaly are in companies like 5-6 digit ids

Comment: @JasonDonnald: `uuid4` will generate UUID objects according to RFC 4122. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4

Comment: @JasonDonnald: If you would like to generate specially formatted ids, you can just write them in your own `Provider`

Answer (score 2):

You can write a small Ruby script using the ["Faker" gem](https://github.com/stympy/faker).

Answer (score 2):

You can generate that data [here](https://www.mockaroo.com/). Also it has some other types of random data such as: email, gps data, IBAN...

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Feel free to expand more on the description and answer.